# Is it possible to show only clicked <td> by hiding all other objects in HTML table?

Tags: javascript

Below is my HTML code snippet. When I click on any td element, that element should be expanded and displayed in tables 100% area by hiding all sibling td elements and tr (other rows) elements. When I click it second time the initial table should be displayed as it is. Is this feasible to implement with Java script? Thanks in advance for any solutions.

```
 <html>
   <head>
    <title>Untitled</title>
   </head>
   <body onload="testHide()">
    <table style="width:100%;height:100%" summary="">
     <tr>
      <td>
       <div id="x1">PANEL 1</div>
      </td>
      <td>
       <div id="x2">PANEL 2</div>
      </td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
      <td>
       <div id="x3">PANEL 3</div>
      </td>
      <td>
       <div id="x4">PANEL 4</div>
      </td>
     </tr>
    </table>
    </body>
     <script type="text/javascript">
      function testHide() {
       alert("I am in");
      }
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: Sure, it is. What have you tried?

Comment: Question is: why a table in the first place? That does not look like tabular data.

Comment: You haven't supplied an attempt, just a table.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. We are using prime faces components in our application, panel grid to show all panels in 2 columns. panel grid is generating above HTML content. So keep my question simple, I just posted generated HTML content. When user clicks on any panel, that should expanded by shrinking all other panels in the Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My JavaScript code has comments for each step to explain how it works. I also suggest you move your styles to css as in my demo rather than using them inline in the html. **[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/oRIzegA/5/edit)**

While the jQuery library can be helpful, it's not at all needed here. jQuery is a huge script and will add to your page loading time. My script is very light. It's always good to know how to do things without the aid of a library!

**Markup:**

```
<table id="myTable">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>PANEL 1</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>PANEL 2</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>PANEL 3</div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div>PANEL 4</div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
//get references to the tds you need to manipulate
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('#myTable td');

//add a click function to each td
for (var i=0; i<tds.length; ++i) {
  addClick(tds[i], i);
}

function addClick(elem, i) {
  //"elem" is the td
  //"i" is the td's number (0-3)
  elem.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    toggle(elem, i);
  });
}

function toggle(elem, i) {
  //toggle other rows
  var otherRows = getSiblings(elem.parentNode);
  for (var h=0; h<otherRows.length; ++h) {
    var row = otherRows[h];
    //get row's current style
    var rowDisplay = row.style.display;
    //this flips the display style (shows if hidden, hides if shown)
    row.style.display = (rowDisplay === '') ? 'none' : '';
  }

  //loop through each td on the current row and show or hide
  var otherCells = getSiblings(elem);
  for (var j=0; j<otherCells.length; ++j) {
    var cell = otherCells[j];
    var display = cell.style.display;
    cell.style.display = (display === '') ? 'none' : '';
  }
}

function getChildren(n, skipMe){
    var r = [];
    var elem = null;
    for ( ; n; n = n.nextSibling ) 
       if ( n.nodeType == 1 && n != skipMe)
          r.push( n );        
    return r;
}

function getSiblings(n) {
    return getChildren(n.parentNode.firstChild, n);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is. I'd recommend a DOM library like [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com).

In this example we handle the core DOM interactions with the [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method to detect clicks, and the [`show`](http://api.jquery.com/show/) / [`hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) shorthands to toggle `display: none` inline CSS on the other table cells.

To find the other table cells, we use the [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/), [`find`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), and [`not`](http://api.jquery.com/not/) [DOM traversal](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/) methods.

Finally, to keep track of state (to determine whether a click should expand or collapse), we use the [`data`](http://api.jquery.com/data/) method.

```
// Whenever a table cell is clicked...
$( 'td' ).on( 'click', function toggle(){
    // ...save a reference to it
    var $td     = $( this );
    // and to the other cells in the same table:
    var $others = $td
            // Go up the DOM tree and find the closest table
            .closest( 'table' )
            // Find all table cells within it
            .find( 'td' )
            // Exclude the current table cell
            .not( $td );

    // Check to see if we've already expanded it
    // (this will be false the first time round)
    if( $td.data( 'expanded' ) === true ){
        // If it is, reveal the others
        $others.show();
        // And save state
        $td.data( 'expanded', false );
    }
    else {
        // Otherwise, hide the others
        $others.hide();
        // And save state
        $td.data( 'expanded', true );
    }
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

In plain JavaScript:

```
var clicktime = 1;

function expand(id) {
  if(clicktime == 1) {
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
      tds[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    document.getElementById(id).style.display = "table-cell";
    document.getElementById(id).style.width = "100%"
    document.getElementById(id).style.height = "100%"
    clicktime = 2;
  } else {
    var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
    document.getElementById(id).style.width = "50%";
    document.getElementById(id).style.height = "50%";
    for(var i = 0; i < tds.length; i++) {
      tds[i].style.display = "table-cell";
    }
    clicktime = 1;
  }
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td id="1" onclick="expand(1)">
   <div id="x1">PANEL 1</div>
  </td>
  <td id="2" onclick="expand(2)">
   <div id="x2">PANEL 2</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td id="3" onclick="expand(3)">
   <div id="x3">PANEL 3</div>
  </td>
  <td id="4" onclick="expand(4)">
   <div id="x4">PANEL 4</div>
  </td>
 </tr>
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6En9G/)

Comment: This is not only encouraging the needless use of inline style, but inline js which is never ok. Please do not use or encourage inline js. https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F